# How change PHP Version to php5.6 and install all module in php5.6

Tags: php, cpanel

1- my script works in appserv { localhost }

**Appserv information**

> Apache Web Server Version 2.4.20
>
> PHP Script Language Version 5.6.26 & 7.0.11
>
> MySQL Database Version 5.7.15
>
> phpMyAdmin Database Manager Version 4.6.4

2- I uploaded the script on my site but it doesn't work well

3- I have changed PHP Version in { MultiPHP Manager } to PHP 5.6 (ea-php56) but not work

4- I changed `htaccess` but not work

Comment: Start with the current configuration *I uploaded the script on my site but it doesn't work well*. What didn't work, what problems are you having - if you are getting errors - start with that and try and solve them rather than just changing versions of software.

Comment: Most people aren't going to click on links to external sites to check what is wrong, you should add details to your question.

Comment: When you click on a link, the timer starts
 but when reloading the page does not work

Comment: There are options that do not appear, such as hide link and delete link

Comment: That link work for my... I can't see whats wrong ;-D

Comment: but when reloading the page timer does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use wampserver. You can change php version simply.

Comment: i need change php version in my server